# how to return a view when calling a action method using jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

helllo folks,
I have a jquery function which is calling a action method and returning same view(current view) what it was,but i want to return a different view(OfferOrderView).how can i perform this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
            $("#Add").click(function () {
                     $.ajax({url: '@Url.Action("OfferOrderView","Sales")',

                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",

                data:{EstId:EstId},
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',


                            success: function (result) {

                               //Doesnt Matter

                            },
                            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                                alert("Failed");
                            }


 public ActionResult OfferOrderView(int EstId)
        {
           var result = SalesManager.GetAllSpecialOffers(EstId);
            return View(result);
        }
```

Comment: You cant with ajax call

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. Your are passing an object containing 4 properties to the method, but that method accepts only an `int` named `EstId` which is not even one of the name/value pairs that you are sending in the request. And you view needs to return a PartialView, not a `View`. Then you add it to the DOM in the seccess callback using `$(someElement).html(result);` and remove the `dataType` option

Comment: Try to use `$.get` or `$.load`

Comment: But it sounds like you actually want a completely different view (not stay on the same page), in which case do not use ajax!

Comment: @stephen muecke,sorry for data,yes i want a totally different view,how can i do this then

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page. Do not use ajax. Just make a normal submit and in that method, use `return RedirectToAction(...)`

Comment: its a jquery foreach loop binded data and im using like this...            '<td> <a href="#" onclick="OfferOrderView(' + obj.Est_id + ')">View</a><td>

Comment: Using f12 key in your browser you can open developer tools, and in developer tools in network tab you can see what returned from server. and you can see any error if happened.

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to change datatype from json to html in your ajax call

```
   dataType: "html",
```

2) you need to set your result with html method

```
*.html(result);
```

3) also you have problems with bindings, see what you send in the request and what you expect.

4) not sure, but if it doesn't help, use PartialView instead of View

```
return PartialView(result);
```

5) if you want to navigate to completely different view, use another approach, for example:

```
$("#Add").click(function(estId) {
    var url = '@Url.Action("OfferOrderView", "Sales")?EstId=' + estId;
    window.location.href = url;
    });
```

Comment: var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("OfferOrderView", "Sales", new { EstId = @EstId }))';
  window.location.href = url; Is this will be in the jquery block only?

Comment: Thanks Nikolay...it was simple ..i was getting in complication

Answer (score 0):

you need to use

```
window.location.href = 'www.yourweburl.com/OfferOrderView.php';
```

Comment: Thanks bro..sometime our brain got stucked..it was so easy and clear

Comment: if this answered your question, please consider accepting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

```
    type: 'POST',
    url: //your url,
    dataType: 'html',
    data:{EstId:EstId},
```

**2.** add **[HttpPost]** above the method and change **View** to **PartialView**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult OfferOrderView(int EstId)
    {
        var result = SalesManager.GetAllSpecialOffers(EstId);
        return PartialView(result);
    }
```